# Deploying WSPs to SP2013: I was not able to connect to the sql data even after deploying the WSPs properly

Tags: sharepoint-2013, wsp, fba

I developed a webapplication `Example1:7575` which uses FBA. Now, I deployed these WSP's to a new server `Production:2525` to get the same functionality of my previous server's webapplication. However, I was not able to fetch the data from sql server and I'm getting the following error: A Membership Provider has not been configured correctly. Check the web.config setttings for this web application.

Actually, I have manually entered the same membership and role providers of my previous server's central admin, security service token & web application's web.config entries to this new web.configs and matched them.

Can someone help me with where I might be doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't fetch data from SQL Server there's probably an issue with permissions to the database. Check the database connection string that FBA is using.  It likely uses Windows authentication to connect - in which case it will be connecting as the user assigned to the app pool for the web application and the secure token service.  Check that the configured app pool identities have permissions to access the sql server databases.

Comment: Thank you so much chris...I have made the changes in the connection string and now I am able to get the desired functionality..I greatly appreciate your time and help :)